# glReadPixels read "out of frames" area

Tags: objective-c, opengl, glreadpixels, off-screen

I draw OpenGL 3200x2000 size textured quads. OpenGLView frame size is set to 940x560. It draws quad as it should. Bun when I try to save it as image (using glReadPixels) and set glReadPixels area from (0,0) to (3200,2000). It creates pixel data 3200x2000, but when I save it to file I see small image part (940x560 from bottom left corner) and whole other area is black. So how can I read offscreen area? I tried using Framebuffer, but its very complicated, errors while creating it and etc... Is there any other solution?

---

#### Situation visualization:

Original image looks like this (3200x2000):
[image]

OpenGLView looks like this (940x560):
[image]

Saved image looks like that (3200x2000):
[image]

Comment: It's [NSOpenGLView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 4):

So you're rendering to the window. Well, the window has a particular size. And nothing exists *outside* of that size.

This is part of something OpenGL calls the "pixel-ownership-test". If a pixel is not owned by the context, then its contents are undefined. Pixels outside of the window are not owned by the context, and therefore their contents are undefined.

This is one reason why [framebuffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) exist: so that you can render outside the size of your window. Though be advised: there is a maximum viewport size limit.

Alternatively, you can render in screen-sized pieces, where you download each piece after each rendering, then move the camera to render the next piece.

Comment: Great detailed answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given much details in terms of code, or the platform.

But I think you should be using offscreen rendering, rather than just reading from the rendered window. If you are unfamiliar with using frame buffer objects, here is a minimal example:

https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/minimalfbo

Edit #1:

Since OP mentioned that the platform is OS X, I am posting my code below, which shows a minimal FBO example in iOS:

https://github.com/glman74/simpleFBO

Comment: I'm developing for OS X. Using Objective-C, but as we know OpenGL is cross-platform. Thank you for the link, i'll check it right now and give feedback.

Comment: Actually again I proved myself that I hate framebuffers. When fallowing example you gave me I get "Framebuffer error". So it means that framebuffer haven't been created. And only god knows why

Comment: I've posted my FBO code for iOS - maybe you can try to port it to OS X.

Comment: When you just load the simplefbo project in xcode and run it in the iOS simulator, what do you get?

Comment: When I run it on iOS simulator it runs OK, but when I take code part where FBO is initialized and add it to OS X project, then it doesn't runs. Says that there is Framebuffer Error